# excludecomment fails when used with newenvironment

Tags: environments, comments

I can hide a `proof` environment using the `comment` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment,amsthm}
\excludecomment{proof}
\begin{document}
    This is always printed.
    \begin{proof}[Answer]
        Hide this.
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

When I try to do the same with an added `newenvironment` command, i.e.,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment,amsthm}
\newenvironment{answer}{\begin{proof}[Answer]}{\end{proof}}
\excludecomment{answer}
\begin{document}
    This is always printed.
    \begin{answer}
        Hide this.
    \end{answer}
\end{document}
```

I get the error:

> \begin{answer} ended by \end{proof}. \end{answer} \begin{document}
>   ended by \end{answer}. \end{answer}
>   Extra \endgroup. \end{answer}

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is because the assigned comment environment `<env>` doesn't process the construction `\begin{<env>}`...`\end{<env>}` as a regular group (from the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/comment/comment.pdf)):

> Note: for an included comment, the `\begin` and `\end` lines act as if they don't exist.
>   In particular, they don't imply grouping, so assignments &c are not local.

A lengthier explanation: The expansion of `\begin{answer}` does result in `\begin{proof}[Answer]`, but the group is immediately closed before searching for `\end{answer}`. Internally, LaTeX keeps track of which group you're in with every call to `\begin`. The macro responsible for holding the information on the `curr`ent `envir`onment is `\@currenvir` which, based on your definition

```
\newenvironment{answer}
  {\begin{proof}[Answer]}
  {\end{proof}}
```

holds `proof` rather than `answer` after expanding `\begin{answer}`. Ultimately the [`comment` package](//ctan.org/pkg/comment)'s search finds `\end{answer}`, but this fails the LaTeX test for a matching environment `\begin`, resulting in the posted error.

In short, it's processed differently than expected.

A way around this is to set the nested environment using a command-form:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{comment,amsthm}

\newenvironment{answer}{\proof[Answer]}{\endproof}
\excludecomment{answer}

\begin{document}

This is always printed.
\begin{answer}
Hide this.
\end{answer}

\end{document}
```

Note the requirement that the `\end{<env>}` for a commented `<env>` should be on a line of its own without spaces:

> The opening and closing commands should appear on a line of their own. No starting
>   spaces, nothing after it.