# Using excludecomment to hide newtcolorbox gives error on end command

Tags: environments, tcolorbox, comments

I am currently trying to use the `comment` package to conditionnaly hide some custom `tcolorbox`, but I keep getting errors. I suspect this [answer addresses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/455211/289403) the root of the problem, but I don't understand how to apply the suggested fix to my own use of `newtcolorbox`...

Here is a MWE (inspired by but a lot more simplified than my current code, of course):

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{myTestTCB}[1][title={default title}]{
    #1
}

\excludecomment{myTestTCB}

\begin{document}

\begin{myTestTCB}[title=custom title]
    hidden content
\end{myTestTCB}

\end{document}
```

which gives me the following error (this is an extract, but as far as I know, it is the first useful message in the log):

```
[...] Excluding 'myTestTCB' comment.
/.../mwe.tex:12: Undefined control sequence.
\endtcolorbox ->\tcb@insert@after@part 
                                       \end {tcb@savebox}\tcb@reset@color \t...
l.12 \end{myTestTCB}
                    
/.../mwe.tex:12: Too many }'s.
\endtcb@savebox ...efalse \color@endgroup \egroup 
                                                  \expandafter \@iiiparbox \...
l.12 \end{myTestTCB}
[...]
```

This MWE works fine when not using `excludecomment`.
How should I proceed to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve your goal without the `comment` package. Simply redefine the `myTestTCB` environment, so that it do nothing. For this, you need to use `\RenewDocumentEnvironment` (from `xparse` package, but you don't need to load it if you have recent LaTeX, as it is yet in his kernel) instead of `renewenvironment` because the former let you to capture the material in the environment, so we can just ignore it in order to not display it.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{myTestTCB}[1][title={default title}]{
    #1
}

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{myTestTCB}{o +b}{}{}

\begin{document}

Text

\begin{myTestTCB}[title=custom title]
    hidden content
\end{myTestTCB}

\end{document}
```

If you need a more advanced solution, you could define 2 commands (`\deactivatemyTestTCB` and `\activatemyTestTCB`). Example:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{myTestTCB}[1][title={default title}]{
    #1
}

\newcommand{\deactivatemyTestTCB}{\RenewDocumentEnvironment{myTestTCB}{o +b}{}{}}

\newcommand{\activatemyTestTCB}{\renewtcolorbox{myTestTCB}[1][title={default title}]{##1}}

\begin{document}

Text

\deactivatemyTestTCB

\begin{myTestTCB}[title=custom title]
    hidden content
\end{myTestTCB}

\activatemyTestTCB

\begin{myTestTCB}[title=custom title]
    visible content
\end{myTestTCB}

\end{document}
```

Note that you need to use `##1` instead of `#1` in definition of `\activatemyTestTCB` because the parameter is embedded.

With this later code, you obtain only the "visible content".

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I had tried something with `renewenvironment` but due to my lack of experience, it didn't work. With your code, it does! And since my real tcolorbox has a way longer declaration, the `activatemyTestTCB` env would need to redeclare it all... but I don't have a use for it anyway. Thanks again!